# Nifi to puthbasejson having error to save special characters

Tags: hbase, apache-nifi

I am trying to put nifi to puthbasejson.
I have data which contains colon (:), comma (,), apostrophe('), double quotes(") and someother special characters.
could you please help me to escape these and put in hbase as they are.

example
today is "Monday" and screen is "1000:1"

Comment: could you provide an example of json that you have, and desired format

Comment: @daggett  this is the example which I am using          {"today":"Monday","screen":"1000:1","details":"\[new resolution\] this is resolved, on [at symbol] 20170102T12:00:02+01:00"}

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution by evaluating json before inserting to validate the correct jsons.

Thank you all